# Перевести значения таблицы в массив. Ошибка в коде

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица, значения вводит пользователь, нужно значения из таблицы перевести в массив в виде матрицы

пока 2 проблемы:

1) создается 2 массива

2) не получается получить значения

Буду рада, если кто-то подскажет как это исправить

```js
$('.button').click(function() {

  var table_A = $('#Atable'),
    row_A = $('tr', table_A),
    coll_A = $('#Atable td input').val(),
    marix_A = [];

  row_A.each(function() {
    marix_A.push($(coll_A, this));
  });
  alert(marix_A);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="input_matrixA" id="Atable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="elem_matrix" placeholder="a1.1" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="elem_matrix" placeholder="a2.1" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="elem_matrix" placeholder="a2.1" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="elem_matrix" placeholder="a2.2" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Весь код тут https://jsfiddle.net/Petryaeva/2vmr6j07/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос был решен

```
$('.button').click(function () {    
    var matrix = [];
    $('#Atable tr').each(function() {
        var values = [];
        $(this).find("input").each(function(){
            values.push($(this).val());
        });
        matrix.push(values);
    });
});
```